# Windows Events 229 and 600, what do they mean?

Tags: windows, event-log

The following event for the RemoteDesktopServices shows up in the EventLog, what does it mean?

```
Event ID: 229,   
Channel: Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational,   
Level: Information,    
Provider: Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS,   
Description: 'CUMRDPProtocolManager::CreateListener(RDP-Tcp) DEBUG/VM/ReverseTCP/ReverseUDP/INET' in CUMRDPProtocolManager::CreateListener at <xxxx, a number> err=[0x0],   
Opcode: Runtime (<XX a 2 digit>), Task: RemoteFX module (<X a digit>)   


Event ID: 600,   
Channel: Windows PowerShell,   
Level: Information,    
Provider: PowerShell,   
Description: Provider "Registry" is Started., 
HostApplication=C:\Windows\System32\RemoteFXvGPUDisablement.exe Disable  
Opcode: , Task: Provider Lifecycle (<X a digit>)
```

Are these usual events in RDP or something else?
What do the descriptions mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What version of Windows is your client and the server running? Are you actively trying to use RemoteFX? What did you do to see that error? As the level is information it is just that, an informational message that should not have any impact and e.g. might just give information about the service working properly.

Comment: If you are using RemoteFX, keep in mind, it’s completely unsupported on supported versions of Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Are these events normal?